# Problems Inserting a CStringW into a std::wostringstream

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, wostringstream

I'm working on converting an MFC program from MBCS to Unicode. I've found that the insertion operator << is working differently with CStringA than with CStringW instances.

```
// char
std::ostringstream c_oss;
CStringA c_s("Hello");
c_oss << c_s;
TRACE("%s\n", c_oss.str().c_str());

// wchar_t
std::wostringstream w_oss;
CStringW w_s(L"World");
w_oss << w_s;
TRACE(L"%s\n", w_oss.str().c_str());
```

I would expect this to print "Hello\nWorld\n" but instead it prints "Hello\n14,5E6,B38\n". That is, it's printing the address of the w_s data rather than the data.

If I debug into w_oss << w_s, I can see that the overload for inserting a const void* is being selected rather than the one for inserting a const wchar_t*. It's working correctly for the char version. If I explicitly apply the case (LPCTSTR) or (const wchar_t*), it works correctly for the wchar_t version.

Any ideas why the wchar_t version is working differently than the char version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wide character version of `operator<<` is a template and as such requires an exact argument match. No user-defined conversion, such as `CStringW::operator wchar_t*()` is implicitly performed.

OTOH the `void*` version of the same operator is not a template and happily uses the user-defined conversion operator.

Comment: Isn't everything you just wrote equally true for the char version of operator<<?

Comment: Normally it would apply to `char*` version too, but I believe there's non-standard non-template version of `operator<<` defined somewhere in the depths of MFC for `char*`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Everything you wrote is correct and along with the information added by @SChepurin and Mr.C64, I've been able to get my code to work correctly. I wish I could select all three answers as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Considering VS2010 SP1, I found that in the `<ostream>` header there is this overload for `std::ostringstream` and `const char*`:

```
template<class _Traits> inline
    basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& operator<<(
        basic_ostream<char, _Traits>& _Ostr,
        const char *_Val)
    {    // insert NTBS into char stream
         ...
```

but there doesn't seem to be a similar overload for `std::wostringstream` and `const wchar_t*`.

If you add it to your source code, sending `CStringW` with `operator<<` seems to work (my personal preference: use `CString::GetString()` method with string streams and `operator<<`):

```
namespace std {

template<class _Traits> inline
    basic_ostream<wchar_t, _Traits>& operator<<(
    basic_ostream<wchar_t, _Traits>& _Ostr,
    const wchar_t *_Val)
{
    ATLTRACE("It's me, the new overload!\n");

    typedef wchar_t _Elem;

    //
    // *** Copy and paste *** the source code from the following overload:
    //
    // template<class _Elem,
    //  class _Traits> inline
    //    basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& operator<<(
    //    basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr, const _Elem *_Val)
    //

    //
    // NOTE: I don't want to infringe any copyright.
    //
    // Moderators please delete the following lines if they
    // infringe any copyright.
    //

    typedef basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> _Myos;

    ios_base::iostate _State = ios_base::goodbit;
    streamsize _Count = (streamsize)_Traits::length(_Val);  // may overflow
    streamsize _Pad = _Ostr.width() <= 0 || _Ostr.width() <= _Count
        ? 0 : _Ostr.width() - _Count;
    const typename _Myos::sentry _Ok(_Ostr);

    if (!_Ok)
        _State |= ios_base::badbit;
    else
    {   // state okay, insert
        _TRY_IO_BEGIN
            if ((_Ostr.flags() & ios_base::adjustfield) != ios_base::left)
                for (; 0 < _Pad; --_Pad)    // pad on left
                    if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(),
                        _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputc(_Ostr.fill())))
                    {   // insertion failed, quit
                        _State |= ios_base::badbit;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (_State == ios_base::goodbit
                        && _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputn(_Val, _Count) != _Count)
                        _State |= ios_base::badbit;

                    if (_State == ios_base::goodbit)
                        for (; 0 < _Pad; --_Pad)    // pad on right
                            if (_Traits::eq_int_type(_Traits::eof(),
                                _Ostr.rdbuf()->sputc(_Ostr.fill())))
                            {   // insertion failed, quit
                                _State |= ios_base::badbit;
                                break;
                            }
                            _Ostr.width(0);
                            _CATCH_IO_(_Ostr)
    }

    _Ostr.setstate(_State);
    return (_Ostr);
}

} // namespace std
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess, nm's answer is correct. The official explanation is rather misty but means the same ([MSDN about IO with std::wcout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72b2swax.aspx)):

> Without the cast, cs is treated as a void* and wcout prints the
>   address of the object. This behavior is caused by subtle interactions
>   between template argument deduction and overload resolution which are
>   in themselves correct and conformant with the C++ standard.

Comment: Those _raw_ C style casts (in the MSDN web page you cited) are not good; I'd prefer a **C++ style cast** like : `CStringW cs(L"..."); std::wcout << static_cast<const wchar_t *>(cs); << std::endl;` or _better_ just use the **`CString::GetString()` method**: `std::wcout << cs.GetString() << std::endl;`.